# I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04. Neither "Software Updater" nor "sudo do-release-upgrade" work

Tags: ubuntu

When I try `sudo do-release-upgrade` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 11, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 11, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

What I've tried so far:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo dist-upgrade

sudo apt autoremove 

sudo do-release-upgrade

sudo update-manager

apt-get install -f

sudo apt install update-manager

sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core

apt-get install python-apt

sudo apt remove python3-apt

sudo apt install python3-apt

sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-34m-i386-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so

sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so

/usr/bin/update-manager

sudo apt clean
```

When I tried:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.bak
```

I got:

`mv: cannot stat '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service': No such file or director`y

Of course after doing all that, I again tried:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo dist-upgrade

sudo apt autoremove 

sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but I am hoping this will help people who currently have this issue.

For me this was fixed by running command:

`sudo apt install --reinstall python3 python python3-minimal --fix-broken`

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried the [step-by-step directions from FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-version/) and it fails, then the alternative is to download the [Ubuntu 18.04 ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) and do a clean installation. This has the advantage of removing old Unity packages and settings, since 18.04 uses GNOME.

Of course, this loses all customization and data, so save your data, and also make a disk image, should something go wrong. Having done both upgrades of 16.04 and complete new installations, I find the second choice is faster and easier, despite the disadvantage of requiring data and additional package reinstallation.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was checking `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`
It had 2 issues /usr/bin/python needs to point to python2.7 and /usr/bin/python3 needs to point to python3.5.

Comment: Thanks it was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> apt-get update

then

> apt-get upgrade

solved the problem. If it asks to force the fix then use the command -f.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3 python python3-minimal --fix-broken
```

works for me